# Use matrices to find the cost of 1 kg of bananas

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Claire and Dale shopped at the same store.

Claire bought 5 kg of apples and 2 kg of bananas and paid altogether $22

Dale bought 4 kg of apples and 6 kg of bananas and paid altogether $33

Use matrices to find the cost of 1 kg of bananas

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: I'm confused on how to solve this in a matrices

Comment: you might like to include an attempt to show that you can do not with a matrix method then? someone then can help you modify your method? as of how the question is now, it's like to be closed.

Comment: 5 kg apples!! What would she do with it? And 6 kg bananas. These guys have serious overeating problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following might be helpful to get you going in the right direction:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 2 \\
4 & 6 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
c_{apples} \\
c_{bananas} \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
22 \\
32 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where $c_{apples}$ is the cost per kg of apples, and $c_{bananas}$ is the cost per kg of bananas. (Please note: this is in the form of $A\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}$).  Both of these are unknown, so you can use matrix methods to find the solution:

$$
\mathbf{x}=
\begin{bmatrix}
c_{apples} \\
c_{bananas} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$.

I hope this helps.